# Internet only in short bursts on Mint 17.2

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint

My cable DHCP ipv4 connection ( i've disabled ipv6 ) is working only in short bursts.
It is mainly visible when performing a sudo apt-get install XXX because is only downloading the first MB and then is dead.

Also:

> --2016-06-11 22:50:39--  http://proof.ovh.net/files/100Mb.dat Resolving proof.ovh.net (proof.ovh.net)... 2001:41d0:2:876a::1,
>   188.165.12.106 Connecting to proof.ovh.net (proof.ovh.net)|2001:41d0:2:876a::1|:80... connected. HTTP request
>   sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 12500000 (12M)
>   [application/octet-stream] Saving to: ‘/dev/null’
>
> 13% [=================>
>   ] 1.693.890   --.-K/s  eta 81s

You can observe the lack of speed indicator, and the progress is stuck at 13% ( it went there in under a second ).

My network card is Network:

> Card: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
>   Controller driver: r8168

I've downloaded the

> LINUX driver for kernel 3.x and 2.6.x and 2.4.x 8.042 2016/5/12

from realtek website, but no performance boost.

I think is not due to my network card, because i've tried with another one, an USB network card with AXIS chipset at it has the same behaviour.

Any hints ?

Comment: Are you connected to a GB switch or a 10/100 switch... can you append the output of `inxi -nxxz` to the question please? EDIT: Wait, I just re-read the last paragraph... Do other devices on the network work correctly?

Comment: Yes they do. Also, if i reboot in Windows 10, it works fine.